# Network statistics reset

Tags: networking

Why network statistics (Rx total  / Tx total) in my RPi resets every 4 GB of traffic? I suspect this is because of *32 bit value limit*. But is it possible to increase this limit?

Comment: Where do you read this information? Is it a widget, program, command?

Comment: Followup: when I run `/sbin/ifconfig eth0`, I see RX/TX larger than 4 GB. So I guess this is a bug of the program you are using.

Comment: Hmm… `ifconfig eth0` shows _exactly_ the same Rx/Tx values as in other statistic/monitoring software I use. 
Perhaps the only difference in Linux distributives? My distr is `Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)`

Comment: I am using the same distribution and have Rx and Tx values in excess of 10 GB ...

Comment: Correction: my stats are for wlan0. Seems it has a larger counter. :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems the general advice is to use a dedicated tool like [vnstat](http://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy/vnstat) for this purpose.

Comment: If you think this is a good answer, please mark it as "accepted", and/or upvote.